# CSS: I want to target each child separately in a container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to assign seperate colors to each `<td>`. One solution is to use classes, but I don't want to crowd the HTML if a simple CSS selector solution exists.

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td>Item 2</td>
  <td>Item 3</td>
  <td>Item 4</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
/* item #1 */
{color: red}

/* item #2 */
{color: blue}

/* item #3 */
{color: green}
```

Comment: Oh, how I *wish* this were possible in pure CSS...

Comment: Apparently it is @DavidThomas :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CSS's `nth-child` selector:

```
td:nth-child(1) {
    color:blue;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    color:brown;
}
td:nth-child(4) {
    color:green;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9Rpx6/)**

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `nth-child` selector to specify a specific element (counting from 1): `td:nth-child(1) { color: red; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/ayTmy/